# Finding $f^{(n)}(0)$ if $f(x)= \frac{x^5}{ 1 + x^2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In an exercise I'm asked the following:

> Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that: $$f(x)= \frac{x^5}{ 1 + x^2}$$
> Determine the value of: $$f^{(n)}(0),\ \ \forall n \in \mathbb N$$

Because we have a fraction, then $f^{(n)}(0)$ will take of the following form, because of the quotient rule for derivatives:

$$f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{P_n(x)}{(1-x^2)^{2n}}$$

So if follows that: $$f^{(n)}(0) = P_n(0)$$

So to solve this we basically need to find out what the numerator of that quotient will be for any $n \in \mathbb N$. That is precisely the part that I'm struggling with. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

You have that $$\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^{2n}.$$
Therefore $$\frac{x^5}{1+x^2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^{2n+5}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^{k}.$$
I let you find $f^{(n)}(0)$ for all $n$.

Comment: Your infinite sum is true when $ |x|<1$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah: And so ? as far as I know, the OP want $f^{(n)}(0)$, so no need to have $|x|\geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

prove that the numerator is $x \cdot Q_n(x)$ for every $n$

Comment: How can I do that? I'm not seeing how that is done.

Comment: you can prove it by induction on $n$ :)